# Can reinterpret_cast<qintptr>(...) be negative?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that is basis for representing hierarchical structure where the bottom object holds actual data:

```
class Data { };

class Item
{
public:
    AItem(AItem *source = nullptr) : m_Data(source ? reinterpret_cast<qintptr>(source) : -reinterpret_cast<qintptr>(new Data)) {}
    virtual ~AItem() { if(m_Data < 0) delete reinterpret_cast<AData*>(-m_Data); }

    qintptr id() const { return m_Data; }
    Data *data() const { return m_Data < 0 ? reinterpret_cast<AData*>(-m_Data) : reinterpret_cast<AItem*>(m_Data)->data(); }

private:
    qintptr m_Data;
};
```

Notice that when no "source" is set in the constructor I create new object of `Data`, reinterpret it as integer, **negate it** and then save it to m_Data. This is crucial as it is used when getting the `Data` object from the hierarchy in `data()` and of course in the destructor.

However this might be a dangerous hack because it relies on both `reinterpret_cast<qintptr>(source)` and `reinterpret_cast<qintptr>(new Data)` never to produce negative integer. Could they?

If they could (and I think they could but I cannot find definitive answer) I will have to add boolean flag to check if the item is base object or not.

Comment: It would be much more portable (read as safer) to simply add the boolean flag.

Comment: This code looks like it negates the pointer and not the data, <s>a pointer cannot be negative</s>

Comment: Well, on a 32-bit Windows you can flag a program as being "large address aware"; in that case, when you allocate memory you can use the first 3GB of memory.  Assuming qintptr is a signed 32-bit value, all of the addresses above 2GB would end up being negative.  So, at least on some platforms it is possible.

Comment: Not sure what `qintptr` is, but if it is any similar to standard `std::intptr_t`, than the answer is "it can be anything, and negative as well".

Comment: The more typical way to do this hack would be to rely on the objects being aligned on an address boundary greater than 1, and then use the lower bits of the address as the flags.  (i.e. if all objects are allocated at addresses which are multiples of 4, you can use the bottom 3 bits as flags).  This is still platform-specific/undefined behaviour, and owacoder's point still stands.

Comment: And really, do not code brittle systems. Instead, use `std::unique_ptr` in your code to hold the value you allocate yourself.

Comment: @SergeyA http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qintptr-typedef And yeah, smart pointers are an alternative. However I will have many of these, think hundreds of millions, so if I could save few bytes on each it will make huge difference.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` should not have any size overhead

Comment: @Resurrection, your own link answers your question. It is the same size as pointer, as thus it can easily become negative.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x However it cannot hold more than one type at a time unless they share the same base.

Comment: @Resurrection, is your system essentially build on `void*` pointers? (typecasted into integers)? I thought the tag of the question is C++...

Comment: @SergeyA It is not, I rarely use casts or void* but as I explained I am trying to shave off bytes where I can because of the amount of data this will support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QT 5 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qintptr-typedef) indicates that `qintptr` is a typedef for either `qint32` or `qint64`, which in turn are typedefs for `signed int` or `signed long long`.

So, yes, the value could be negative. You will have to write proper code instead of using the "sign bit as extra boolean flag" hack.